# How to round off the float values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Table1

```
Id value

001 2.3
002 1.3
003 3
004 5.3
...
...
```

value column datatype is float

Note:

value column will be `.3` always, it will not come like `.1, .2, .4, .5 to .9`

Now i want to display .5 instead of .3 for all the values...

Expected Output

Id value

```
001 2.5 
002 1.5
003 3
004 5.5
...
...
```

How to make a query for this.

Need SQL Query Help

Comment: `SELECT [value]+.2 FROM some_table`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx) function to get your result

```
 Declare @Sample Table
 (ID int ,
 value float)

 Insert into @Sample
 values
(001,2.3),(002,1.4),(003,3),(004,5.3)

 Select ID,round(value/5,1)*5 from @Sample
```

If the value is greater than .3 then it will be rounded to .5 and if it is less than .3 then the integer value will be retrieved

Comment: The logic behind is when you have 2 decimal places you can round off based on the 2nd decimal value for example 2.38 it will round off to 2.4 so based upon that you divide the number 2.3 by 5 which will give you .46 which when rounded off will retrieve .5 and now again u multiply by 5 which will give you the desired result

Comment: In simple logic is to get perfect accurate reciprocal .Hence dividing and multiplying float numbers by 5

Answer (score 0):

You can use the floor function to figure out whether there is a decimal component

Please try the following query

```
update table1 set value = value + 0.2 
where value > floor(value);
```

Comment: What is the error that you're getting? I am using SQLFiddle set to SQL-Server 2008